# toast message compile error inside android java method

Tags: android, compiler-errors, toast

I have used toast in android to display messages many times and never had a problem, this includes putting it inside and outside of methods.   however this time for some reason the compiler does not allow it to work.  Why does it not allow toast to be put inside of this method shown below?

in this code I tried both types of context, "ThumbnailsActivity.class" and "this".

the method decodeSampleBitmapFromResource is inside the Android class ThumbnailsActivity.java that extends Activity.  Nothing is unusual here.

```
  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fileName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);

        // both of the toasts shown here have compile errors

    Toast.makeText(ThumbnailsActivity.class, "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Toast.makeText(this, "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}//end decodeSampledBitmapfromresource method
```

Comment: Use getApplicationContext() instead of this

Comment: try `ThumbnailsActivity.this` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chanhe your method as:

```
public  Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fileName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            // both of the toasts shown here have compile errors

        Toast.makeText(ThumbnailsActivity.this, "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(this, "TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);



    }//end decodeSampledBitmapfromresource method
```

put all toast before return statement and also remove static from method if you want to access non static context

Comment: yes, this works, i did not first notice that the toasts were after the return statements,  now after moving them above the return it compiles.

Comment: i don't understand why this toast compiles fine before the return statement but does not compile after it.

Comment: @Kevik : as you known `return` is the last statement in most language's.if you do this in android you will get `Unreachable code` error in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call current `Activity`'s `Context` directly from a `static` method.

You can pass current `Activity`'s `Context` as param to `static` method or make your method non-static.

Answer (score 0):

U just write on getApplicationContext() and then check now,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"TEST",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```